# Kivy selfie application

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to make an app that allows me to take pictures. I've tried to copy different examples that allow to do this, but I always get the same error:

```
     self._camera = CoreCamera(index=self.index, stopped=True)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

If it helps, this is the latest code I've tried:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button


class CameraExample(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Create a camera object

        self.cameraObject = Camera(play=False)

        self.cameraObject.play = True

        self.cameraObject.resolution = (300, 300)  # Specify the resolution

        # Create a button for taking photograph

        self.camaraClick = Button(text="Take Photo")

        self.camaraClick.size_hint = (.5, .2)

        self.camaraClick.pos_hint = {'x': .25, 'y': .75}

        # bind the button's on_press to onCameraClick

        self.camaraClick.bind(on_press=self.onCameraClick)

        # add camera and button to the layout

        layout.add_widget(self.cameraObject)

        layout.add_widget(self.camaraClick)

        # return the root widget

        return layout

    # Take the current frame of the video as the photo graph

    def onCameraClick(self, *args):
        self.cameraObject.export_to_png('/kivyexamples/selfie.png')


# Start the Camera App

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CameraExample().run()
```

I've also tried to install the opencv-python, which is something that many people recommended, however it still returns the same error.

Comment: Your posted error doesn't seem to match your posted code. Please post a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it actually does return the error to me. This code and others I tried were functioning perfectly on the computers of the people I got them from. I believe my computer lacks some package or I have not installed something I should, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I just tried this code again and I get the same error

Comment: @ApuCoder I'm curious: what was the output you got from the program?

Comment: No issues, ran as expected. Make sure you have installed all dependencies properly and have permission (if applicable) to use camera.